# Does 'sings a song of significance' literally mean 'sing'?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, figurative-language

Does ' sing a song" here mean literally 'sing"?

> - Whatever form it takes, there is in happiness the kind of constant which enjoyment cannot bring us: happiness does not lie in filling time with delight; it is what makes my one life worthwhile. It **sings a song of significance** in the center of my soul. What makes me happy when I look back on my life as years go by is that I have done something with it that had meaning.*

Comment: Who or what do you think is “literally” singing in the center of someone’s soul?

Comment: IMO the author has deliberately written an alliterative sentence – with verbs and nouns all beginning with the **s** sound.

Comment: Back in the 70s somebody wrote a book about Bob Dylan called ***Sing a Song of Significance*** - probably punning on [***Sing a Song of Sixpence***](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-26667,00.html#:~:text='Sing%20a%20Song%20of%20Sixpence,captain%20Blackbeard%20to%20recruit%20pirates.&text=The%20King's%20ships%20were%20the,dish'%20to%20set%20before%20him.), which was originally "pirate slang" (six pence plus a hipflask of rye whisky being the pirate's weekly wage). But apart from that long-forgotten book, the ***Significance*** version has no currency, so it's POB

Comment: @ColleenV Actually, I know it does not mean literally 'sing'. I wonder about it. Which word or phrase can replace this?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Look at your own source!  If you scroll down in says The "pirate slang" story was created to parody urban myths by snopes.  It was supposed to be so ridiculous that it could never become an urban myth itself....https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/mostly-true-stories/

Comment: @JamesK: Can't win 'em all! But I still think that Dylan bio title is a deliberate pun - whereas OP's instance is probably just an accidental similarity (*perhaps* influenced at the subconscious level).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a metaphor. Note he says "sing ... in the center of my soul". You can't literally sing in the center of your soul. (Or at least, I'm not sure what that would mean.) The writer is using the word sing as a metaphor, a symbol, for "experience" or "feel".

Comment: @jat Actually, I know it does not mean literally 'sing'. I wonder about it. Which word or phrase can replace this?

Comment: Anything literal will not sound as poetic. I presume what the writer literally means is, "It makes me think about things of significance" or "It makes me feel significant."

Comment: can it mean "It brings a sense of happiness and satisfaction to my soul"?

Comment: @user70732 Yes. I tried to replace the word "sing" without changing the other key word in the sentence, "significance". But if you want a somewhat freer rewording, yes, you''ve caught the essence of it.

Comment: I really, really do not understand people don't accept clear, simple answers like these. I guess they are looking for eggs in their beer.